# GA4 Admin API for .Net throwing Internal error on CustomDimensions.Patch

Tags: c#, .net, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

I'm trying to update a GA4 dimension via the GA4 API using the .Net library. I've got to the point where it responds with an Internal Error, so not much of a clue why it is failing. Very similar code works fine for patching a CustomMetric.

```
var service = new GoogleAnalyticsAdminService(...); 

var request = service.Properties.CustomDimensions
    .Patch(new GoogleAnalyticsAdminV1alphaCustomDimension()
    {
        Description = "Same description",
        DisplayName = "New display name"
    }, "properties/1234567890/customDimensions/1234567890");

request.UpdateMask = "description,display_name";

await request.ExecuteAsync(cancellationToken); 

// Causes:
// Google.GoogleApiException
//   HResult=0x80131500
//   Message=Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
// Internal error encountered. [500]
// Errors [
//  Message[Internal error encountered.] Location[ - ] Reason[backendError] Domain[global]
// ]
```

Comment: error 500. It may be on api side not on your side.

Comment: It is a beta api. Not sure how to report this sort of thing outside of here.

Answer (score 1):

Tony,

Thank you for reporting this, we will update this thread once the issue is fixed.

Ilya,
The Google Analytics API Team

Comment: A quick update: the original issue is fixed and the `customsDimensions.patch()` operation should succeed now, as long as both `description` and `displayName` fields are updated in the same call. The complete fix will be rolled out soon. Thanks!